# ERROR 1054 (42s22): unknown column 'action' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, updating, describe

Firstly, why does updating this trigger work?

```
CREATE TABLE employees_audit (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    employeeNumber INT NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    changedat DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    action VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TRIGGER before_employee_update 
    BEFORE UPDATE ON employees
    FOR EACH ROW 
 INSERT INTO employees_audit
 SET action = 'update',
     employeeNumber = OLD.employeeNumber,
     lastname = OLD.lastname,
     changedat = NOW();
```

And updating this trigger gets me an error. I update the table with a simple update and set code using the where clause on both the codes.

```
CREATE TABLE Salespeople_audit(
  EmpID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  FName Varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  LName Varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TRIGGER before_Salepeople_update 
    BEFORE UPDATE ON Salespeople 
    FOR EACH ROW 
 INSERT INTO Salespeople_audit
 SET action = 'update',
     EmpID = OLD.EmpID,
     FName = OLD.FName;
```

Comment: I tested your code using MySQL 5.7.27, and got no error. I suspect your employees_audit table doesn't actually have a column named `action`.

Comment: you insert is wrong, empId is autoincrement, so why do you set it ? action doesn't exist and Lname is missing, but it is defined as NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

There is no action field configure in this create table:

```
CREATE TABLE Salespeople_audit(
    EmpID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    FName Varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    LName Varchar(25) NOT NULL
);
```